How to ensure Temurin OpenJDK, when installed, uses static libraries, not dynamic libraries?
The Temurin OpenJDK builds which are posted on GitHub include files with "static-libs" in their filenames. I assume (dangerous, I know…) the hotspot files use dynamic libraries.
What is the "proper" way to convert installed JDK and JRE such that they use static libraries?
If possible, please explain for all the supported OS platforms.
